# Passing session variable in ajax with coldfusion 9

Tags: session, coldfusion

I'm trying to create an online chat program for my web users to speak to a salesperson live. I use an ajax jquery command to refresh the chat, which is stored in a database. The problem I'm running into is it is losing the session variable that identifies the user on the ajax call, but it only seems to do this to some users. Is there some setting for coldfusion that I'm missing?

Should I have any specific settings set in my CF Administrator?

```
<cfapplication name="Chat Room"
           clientmanagement="Yes"
           sessionmanagement="Yes"
           sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#" >

<cfset session.UserID = #new_session.UserID# >


 window.onload = function() 
     {
        setInterval("ReloadChatWindow();", 2500);
     }; 

function ReloadChatWindow()
    { 
        $.ajax({url: "messages.cfm", success: function(result){
            $("#ChatLog").html(result);
        }});

        $("#ChatLog").scrollTop($("#ChatLog")[0].scrollHeight);
    }
```

## new_session.UserID# is just from a database insert (the user provides their name and I assign them the userID.

Only one domain uses the session, there are no cross domain calls.

Comment: where are you getting `new_session.UserID` and why bother setting a new session scope?

Comment: Try turning J2EE sessions **on** from CF Administrator `SERVER SETTINGS` > `Memory Variables`

Comment: Are the clients that lose sessions ever working correctly or do they always drop sessions? Are they all using the same domain or do you have multiple domains hitting this app?

Comment: Rejith I turned on J2EE this morning per your suggestion. Will come back with results.

Comment: J.T. I can't be sure, the people who experience the problem don't try again and I've been unable to replicate the issue myself.

Comment: What file is this? Is this your "Application.cfm" file or are you using `<cfapplication...>` in a regular file?

Comment: The first part is my Application.cfm file. The js part is in an index file.

Comment: It would be better if your setInterval reloaded a hidden element rather than the whole chat transcript. Can you send your exact code? - your javacript is not wrapped in `<script>` which would definitely be a problem, unless you just didn't copy and past these here for terseness.

Comment: See J.T.'s comments. CF can allow so strange stuff with cross-domain sessions, especially if you have multiple server instances on different sub-domains. We had this same issue when one CF server on the main domain was using site wide sessions and our server on the sub-domain had the same thing set. We had to switch ours to J2EE to fix the issue. So do you have other servers/domains also running CF?

Comment: We do have other servers and domains running CF; I switched to J2EE and haven't yet had a report about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Session variables expire so you need to check if they are available before you can use them. In your messages.cfm file you have to check if the user still have a valid session and if it doesn't redirect them to the login page. If they do have a valid session you can update the messages.